# Netbeans com erro no copyfiles

Tags: java

[image: O erro esta na caixa de saída]Pessoal estou trabalhando no meu tcc que se trata de um site para meu campus mais especificadamente o controle de frota do mesmo.
Entao oque acontece é o seguinte eu trabalho no meu campus e em casa só copio o proj da pasta netbeansprojets e colo no meu pc em casa, porém hoje fui fazer este mesmo processo e o netbeans estourou um erro que nunca tinha visto eu ja desinstalei o netbeans e instalei dnv porem n adiantou alguem ai pode me ajudar estarei deixando a imagem do erro desde já agradeço!

ERRO:

```
 ant -f C:\\Users\\VALDELIRIO\\Documents\\NetBeans\\Transiz -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild -DforceRedeploy=false -Dbrowser.context=C:\\Users\\VALDELIRIO\\Documents\\NetBeans\\Transiz "-Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=[Netbeans Install]NetBeans8.2java2antextraorg-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar" clean dist
Could not load definitions from resource org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/copylibstask/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
init:
undeploy-clean:
deps-clean:
do-clean:
Deleting directory C:\Users\VALDELIRIO\Documents\NetBeans\Transiz\build
check-clean:
clean:
Could not load definitions from resource org/netbeans/modules/java/j2seproject/copylibstask/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\VALDELIRIO\Documents\NetBeans\Transiz\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\VALDELIRIO\Documents\NetBeans\Transiz\build\web\META-INF
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\VALDELIRIO\Documents\NetBeans\Transiz\build\web\META-INF
Created dir: C:\Users\VALDELIRIO\Documents\NetBeans\Transiz\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\VALDELIRIO\Documents\NetBeans\Transiz\build\web\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF
Copying 152 files to C:\Users\VALDELIRIO\Documents\NetBeans\Transiz\build\web
Copied 28 empty directories to 2 empty directories under C:\Users\VALDELIRIO\Documents\NetBeans\Transiz\build\web
library-inclusion-in-archive:
C:\Users\VALDELIRIO\Documents\NetBeans\Transiz\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1007: Problem: failed to create task or type copyfiles
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
FALHA NA CONSTRUÇÃO (tempo total: 2 segundos)
```

Comment: Adicione o código que estoura esse erro em forma de texto.

Comment: n sei como mandar o codigo formatado direito aqui no site pq e minha 1 vez fazendo pergunta

Comment: Clique em [edit] cole o código na pergunta, depois, selecione ele todo e clique no icone `{}` para formata-lo